# How to get unread mail from the specific folder

Tags: c#, outlook-2007

I am using below code to check unread mail from the outlook
and everything is working fine for the default inbox folder

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace oNS;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Explorer oExp;

    oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    oNS = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

    oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    oExp = oFolder.GetExplorer(false);
    oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items items = oFolder.Items;

    foreach (Object mail in items)
    {
        if ((mail as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem) != null && (mail as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem).UnRead == true)
        {
           string sasd= (mail as OutLook.MailItem).Subject.ToString();

        }
    }
```

But I want to check another folder [which I have created [Name = "Inbox_Personal"]]. How can I do that?

**Edit 1**

Any suggestion or reference to the tutorial will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fld = (Outlook.Folder)app.Session.GetFolderFromID("Inbox_Personal", storeID);
```

I can't remember where to get the store ID from, but should be stored in your session object oder default folder object.

**EDIT**
I've looked up in a project now: StoreID in GetFolderFromID is optional (Type.Missing).

Default Store ID can be found here:

```
app.Session.DefaultStore.StoreID
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.defaultstore(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I am stucked on store ID... :-(

Comment: I am not getting DefaultStore property for oApp.Session .

Comment: Should be there. Or try it without DefaultStoreID

Answer (score 3):

I use something similar to the following to access different accounts in Outlook (2007 and greater; before 2007 stores do not exist and you simply need to look at the folders)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSapce oNS = oApp.GetNameSpace(“Mapi”);
foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store oAccounts in oNS.Stores)
{ 
    // get the right account:
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store oDesiredAccount;
    foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store oAccount in oAccounts)
    {
        if(oAccount.DisplayName.ToLower.Equals(“<<Name of Account>>”)
        {
            oDesiredAccount = oAccount;
        }
    }

    // do stuff with the account
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder root = oAccount.GetRootFolder();
    // ....
}
```